# Amazon AWS allowing access to bucket getting error in logs and on app

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I posted this question on AWS forums, but the forums are dead there and I am not getting a response. Here is my question;

I have enabled logs for my bucket, and have gotten a few logs put through. Im not sure why half of them are there unless people are clicking on my app on heroku which is quite a unique address, and is basically, just a test app. I enabled them as I can not get Imagemagick (on heroku) to work with AWS S3 buckets and wanted to see what the log was if at all a log on the request made to the bucket if AWS was rejecting the request or it was something to do with heroku or my app. I am getting this error on all of the entries in the logs

```
"This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>6B82BA85E0325F6F</RequestId>
<HostId>T5xEfKSuRO4+sWe/8dWLHdNzEELoneWTFnryX1k1irVo/IhFL+8TfYNAwX0b9EbP85zVlVOwo9w=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I am wondering what the error is in cause of?

I created a group and created and added a IAM user and added the AmazonS3FullAccess policy so that the user can read and write objects to ANY bucket. I have the correct user keys added to heroku for my app so I am wondering the problem.

Comment: Can you please rewrite this question more clearly?  I can't tell which logs you're talking about reading where.  The message you posted looks like you attempted to access a private s3 file in the browser without signing the request, but I don't understand where that fits in.

Comment: You can enable logs in your bucket in AWS console I did this and that is the error I am getting on all logs. I am trying to upload a image on my app at heroku and I can not do that as heroku just displays a error message. Not sure if that helps?

Comment: you mean that's the error you're getting when you try to download the logs from s3 through the s3 console?  I don't understand the part about the image upload either.  Do you have an actual error for that you can add to your question?

Comment: No I mean these logs are being sent to the s3 bucket daily I just enabled them to see requests to the bucket.

Comment: You mean, you were already requesting things in s3, but you "just enabled" logging for the bucket?  Is that what you're saying?  And you can't read the logs?

Comment: Yes exaclty. But I can read the logs or atleast the properties of the log and the link to the request message. Ok so your saying that I am getting a error to the message I am trying to see, its, not a logging error as such?

Comment: Yes, if you're getting that error when you try to click to download the file in the s3 console , it probably means your user doesn't have permissions to read that file - as opposed to listing the bucket and learning the facts of its existence, so to speak

Comment: For log delivery I have "upload/delete", "view permissions" ticked but not "list" and "edit permissions", so maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131110/discussion-between-dan-farrell-and-lee-eather).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was as Dan Farrel said I did not have permission to read the log file but that wasnt the main problem I was trying to resolve.

To fix the image upload issue I had the region set to sydney which is closest to me but actually had to be the ap-southeast-2 region at heroku even though at AWS you set it as just sydney.

A list of regions can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)